# Is there any simplification for this?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Is there any simplification for this?

```
$query = $this->link->prepare('SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1')
$query->bindParam(':id', $id);
$query->execute();
$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
unlink($row['avatar']);
$query = $this->link->prepare('DELETE FROM test WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1');
$query->bindParam(':id', $id);
$query->execute();
```

Comment: why do you need to `SELECT` first ? Just go ahead to delete it. (p.s. `DELETE` does not need `LIMIT 1`, assuming `id` is primary key & unique)

Comment: @ShivanRaptor The `SELECT` retrieves the file name that is unlinked before the `DELETE` runs.

Comment: You just `unlink` the fetched result. Not affecting anything else. Doesn't make sense if there is no extra code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like to advise people to skip using query parameters. You should get into the habit of doing it.

It's actually not hard, and it makes it simpler to write queries because you never have to think about whether you got the right kind of escaping and quoting. I find it makes my code look more clear.

I've always been puzzled how people learn that they need to use bindParam() for everything with PDO. It's simpler in most cases to pass an array of parameters to execute(). The only case when I typically use `bindParam()` is if I need to pass a NULL value.

Also you don't need to use named parameters, you can use positional parameters (but don't mix these parameter types in a given query).

`fetchColumn()` is simpler if you only need one column. Speaking of which, avoid `SELECT *` when you don't need all the columns.

If you are querying for a specific `id`, assuming that's the primary key, then you don't need `LIMIT 1`. There can be at most one row for a specific value in any unique key.

I assume you've enabled the exception-based error reporting. If not, you should check the result from each call to `prepare()` and `execute()` because they return **false** on error.

```
$query = $this->link->prepare('SELECT avatar FROM test WHERE id = ?')
$query->execute([$id]);
$avatar = $query->fetchColumn();
unlink($avatar);
$query = $this->link->prepare('DELETE FROM test WHERE id = ?');
$query->execute([$id]);
```

PS: The short syntax for arrays, like `[$id]`, requires PHP 5.4

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the good question. To my utter disappointment, such questions are extremely rare on this site.

> Is there any simplification for this?

Sure.

This is called "programming".
Although for the average PHP user programming stands for just putting several predefined blocks together, like LEGO bricks, in reality programming stands more for *invention*, for creating something *new*. And no less for *optimizing* too, for taking less moves for the same action.

A programmer could always create a *function* to encapsulate repeated tasks. Eventually he may wish to put such functions together into a class, but that's not the point.

As you can see, most of your operators just repeated ones. Every time you see a repetition you know for sure there can be a *function* or at least a loop.

Here is your code using [my attempt in programming](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql), aimed (beside extra safety) to the very code shortening:

```
$name = $this->link->getOne('SELECT avatar FROM test WHERE id = ?i', $id)
unlink($name);
$this->link->query('DELETE FROM test WHERE id = ?i', $id);
```

As you can see, this code is Extra DRY (stands for Don't Repeat Yourself) - all the repeated code is just taken away into internals.

Well, as you can see, my class is built upon mysqli. but of course something similar can be done even using ugly PDO, using wrapper sort of [one I posted recently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19476687/285587):

```
$name = $this->link->query('SELECT avatar FROM test WHERE id = ?', [$id], "one");
unlink($name);
$this->link->query('DELETE FROM test WHERE id = ?', [$id]);
```

By the way, taking *programming* little further you may shorten this code even more:

```
unlink($avatar_dir.$id.".png");
$query = $this->link->query('DELETE FROM test WHERE id = ?i', $id);
```

as avatar image obviously don't need no dedicated name and just `id` can serve perfectly, saving you extra field in database and extra query. All avatars can be converted to single format at the time of upload, to reduce the headache even more.